# Find the values of the natural number $N$ for which there are exactly 15% among $1$ to $N$ that are divisible by 6

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have found the answer, but I think it is tedious.

I started by stating that $N$ must satisfy $0.15N=\lfloor\frac{N}{6}\rfloor$.

Let $\lfloor\frac{N}{6}\rfloor=x$ where $\frac{N}{6}\leq x<\frac{N}{6}+1$, and $\alpha=\frac{N}{6}-x$, where $0\leq \alpha<1$.

So, $N=6\alpha+6x$. Substituting this equation into $0.15N=\lfloor\frac{N}{6}\rfloor$, we get:

$0.15(6\alpha+6x)=x$

$0.1x=0.9\alpha$

$x=9\alpha$

Since $0\leq \alpha<1$, $0\leq 9\alpha<9$, so $0\leq x<9$.

Then I substituted all possible values of $x$, minding that $x$ must be an integer to get that the possible values of $N$ are $20$ or $40$.

Instead of substituting values of $x$, is there a more efficient method to find the possible values of $N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we take a look at the equation:
$$
0.15N=\left\lfloor\frac{N}{6}\right\rfloor
$$
The right-hand side is an integer, so the left-hand side must be an integer. To make $0.15N$ an integer, $N$ must be divisible by $20$. Let's say $N = 20M$ (with $M$ a positive integer). We insert that and get
$$
3M=\left\lfloor\frac{10M}{3}\right\rfloor
$$
We then rewrite this into the inequality
$$
3M \leq \frac{10M}3 < 3M + 1
$$
We can multiply by $3$ on all sides to get
$$
9M \leq 10M < 9M + 3
$$
The first inequality is always true for positive $M$, so we may ignore that. The second inequality tells us
$$
10M < 9M + 3\\
M < 3
$$
which only leaves the possibilities $M = 1$ or $M = 2$, corresponding to $N = 20$ or $N= 40$.